# Integration over time

Tags: time-series, integral

Can someone explain this step :

$\frac{1}{t_n-t_1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}[\theta_i + \frac{\theta_{i+1}-\theta_{i}}{t_{i+1}-t_i}(t-t_i)]dt $

to

$\frac{1}{t_n-t_1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{\theta_{i}+\theta_{i+1}}{2}(t_{i+1}-t_i) $

Comment: In applied math problems, simple calculations can look messy due to the appearance of incidental values.  You can see through to the essence of the problem by focusing on the variable of integration: how exactly does it enter into the integrand?  In this case it's apparent that each integral is of the form $\int (at+b)\mathrm{d}t$ for constants $a$ and $b,$ so that computing them amounts to finding $\int t\, \mathrm{d}t.$ I'm sure you know how to do that.  The rest is algebra, which has been done for you in the second line of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to compute the integral:
\begin{align*}
\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}[\theta_i + \frac{\theta_{i+1}-\theta_{i}}{t_{i+1}-t_i}(t-t_i)]dt &= \int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} \theta_i dt + \frac{\theta_{i+1}-\theta_{i}}{t_{i+1}-t_i}\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} (t - t_i)dt \\
&= \theta_i(t_{i+1} -t_i) + \frac{\theta_{i+1}-\theta_{i}}{t_{i+1}-t_i} \Big [ \frac{t^2}{2} -t t_i\Big ]_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} \\
&= \theta_i(t_{i+1} -t_i) +  \frac{\theta_{i+1}-\theta_{i}}{t_{i+1}-t_i} \Big ( \frac{t_{i+1}^2}{2} -t_{i+1} t_i - \frac{t_{i}^2}{2} + t_i^2 \Big ) \\
&= \theta_i(t_{i+1} -t_i) +  \frac{\theta_{i+1}-\theta_{i}}{2(t_{i+1}-t_i)} \Big ( t_{i+1}^2 -2t_{i+1} t_i +  t_i^2 \Big ) \\
&=  \theta_i(t_{i+1} -t_i) +  \frac{\theta_{i+1}-\theta_{i}}{2(t_{i+1}-t_i)} \Big ( t_{i+1} - t_i \Big )^2 \\
&= \theta_i(t_{i+1} -t_i) +  \frac{(\theta_{i+1} - \theta_{i})(t_{i+1}-t_i)}{2} \\
&= \frac{(\theta_{i+1} + \theta_{i})(t_{i+1}-t_i)}{2}.
\end{align*}